# How can I add embed attachments in WordPress REST response?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I use `WP REST API 2.0` for REST API support. How can I get attachments in `_embedded` property of wordpress response? I passed `_embed` parameter but I did not get `wp:attachment` object. Fully url: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed`

[image]

I expect response, like [this](https://ustwo.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&page=2):

[image]

Comment: You need to supply more information about what you have tried.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm using latest version of Wordpress and `WP REST API 2.0` plugin without modifications. Is it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add specific action for that with `register_rest_field` function.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){register_rest_field('your_post_type', 'field_to_show_in_response', array('get_callback' => 'func_to_get_meta_data', 'update_callback' => null, 'schema' => null));});
```

Now in your `func_to_get_meta_data` you have to call `get_attached_media` for example for all medias.

```
function func_to_get_meta_data($obj, $name, $request){return get_attached_media('image', $obj['id']);}
```

In this example i get all images attached to a post or custom post.